# https read timeout in AWS lambda running on Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Code works locally and there are other outbound requests elsewhere in the lambda that work fine. I'm only making an occasional request. Locally the endpoint responds under a second.  `Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.nasdaq.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)`

```
def _scraper(self) -> dict:
    params = {'date': self._date_str()}
    page = requests.get(self._url(), headers=self._headers(), params=params, timeout=60)

    return page.json()

def _date_str(self) -> str:
    date_obj = datetime.now()
    return date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def _url(self):
    return 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/dividends'

def _headers(self):
    return {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'DNT': "1",
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0)'}
```

Comment: [node.js - How to make an external api call within an AWS Lambda function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106048/how-to-make-an-external-api-call-within-an-aws-lambda-function)

Comment: Is your AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a reason why you have done this?